# How the conditional probability is being calculated in Rejection sampling

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, rejection-sampling, accept-reject

In a class lecture, the "Acceptance-rejection algorithm" was presented as follows:

> To generate $ \sim ()$, Find density $g$ satisfying
>   $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}<=c$ for some constant $c$ for all $t \in domain(f)$
>   with $f(t)>0$ and from which rv's can be generated. For each rv
>   required,
>
> 1. Generate $Y \sim g $
> 2. Generate $U \sim U(0,1)$
> 3. If $U \leq \frac{f(t)}{cg(t)}$ accept Y and return $X = Y$ otherwise go back to step 1.
>
> In step 3, we see that $P(accept|Y=y)=P(U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}|Y=y)=\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)})$

I do not understand how can we derive the last staement:

> $P(accept|Y=y)=P(U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}|Y=y)=\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)})$

I understand this is a very basic thing but I am stuck in it. From what I understand, $P(accept|Y=y)$ should be equal to $\frac{P(accept, Y=y)}{P(Y = y)}$
But how are we calculating the $P(accept, Y=y)$? A break down of the derivation will be very helpful for my understanding.

Comment: Apply the definition of "$U\sim U(0,1)$" to compute the chance in (3), after first making sense of what the undefined variable "$t$" might possibly mean in (3).

Comment: Thank you! So here we are using $P(U \leq u) = u$, right? If that is the case then is this assumption correct: $P(accept|Y=y)$ should be equal to $\frac{P(accept, Y=y)}{P(Y = y)}$? If that is true then how to calculate P(accept, Y=y)? Is it simply $P(accept) * P(Y = y)$?

Comment: You might be overthinking this: you don't need to apply any definitions of conditional probability.  Indeed, the notation probably is getting in your way: in (3), write "$y$" instead of "$t.$"  Since you have already observed the event $Y=y,$ the only probability you need to calculate is $\Pr(U \le f(y)/(cg(y))).$